# How to implement SSL handshake(Hello message) with Visual C++?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, ssl, https

How to implement SSL handshake(Hello message) with Visual C++?

Now I use Wireshark(image 1) to check if I can send a SSL Hello Message or not.

So far I think I should finished this with 2 Windows programming tool:

1.CNG(Cryptography API: Next Generation)

2.Winsock

According to SSL sequence diagram(image 2) , first of all , I hope I can send a Client Hello to SSL Server?
Does anyone knows how to implement it or related resources?

Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSvbi.jpg)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSvbi.jpg)

Comment: You don't. I mean you don't implement SSL yourself, but use an existing library that will do it for you. The only valid reason to not use a library would be to learn the internals of SSL. Once you done that you should throw it away because it *will* have bugs and security holes. While common and popular libraries might still have bugs and holes (see e.g. [heartbleed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heartbleed)) those are fewer than you will have.

Comment: [Creating a Secure Connection Using Schannel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374782.aspx)

Comment: I have to do this because I have to make a performance test.

Comment: I've just found a useful project called " A Working TCP Client and Server With SSL " on codeproject . com And sent a successful handshake request